# Control all music players using a single app

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

I'm looking to make an android app that receives some data from the internet, and based on that, play, pause, skip a track or go to the previous track on whatever music player was playing last. Ideally, I want it to work on all music players, but worst case scenario- it should work with Amazon prime music, google play music, apple music and Saavn.

I've heard it's not possible for me to do this. But I know that we can control media players using headset buttons. Is it possible for me to simulate these buttons from my own app?

```
package com.example.hynd.musicchanger;
import java.lang.*;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresPermission;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previous);
    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    previous.setOnClickListener(this);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v)
{
    long eventtime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.previous:

            Intent prevIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON, null);
            KeyEvent prevEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,   KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS, 0);
            prevIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, prevEvent);
            sendOrderedBroadcast(prevIntent, null);
            Log.d("Going to last", "Going to last");
            break;

        case R.id.next:
            Intent nextIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON, null);
            KeyEvent nextEvent = new KeyEvent(eventtime, eventtime, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT, 0);
            nextIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, nextEvent);
            sendOrderedBroadcast(nextIntent, null);
            Log.d("Going next", "Going next");

            break;

        default:
            Log.d("WTF happened?", "Nothing happened");

    }
}



}
```

This is what I've got going right now, but this is not working well on most apps, and not at all on some apps.

Comment: you won't be able to achieve your task. Also I don't think that the other apps (like google play music) would like to provide control over them to your app.

Comment: Headsets are able to control music on press of buttons right? Is it possible for me to simulate those buttons?

Comment: that is the question you should have asked I think. Edit this question or ask new one. But make sure you search before asking.